# Operations with decimal numbers from a C++ program

Tags: ibm-midrange

The IBM i standard library provides the [_DecimalT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=program-using-decimalt-class-template) class for working with decimal numbers. However, compared to working on this type from C or RPG programs, working through the _DecimalT class is significantly inferior in performance (for a division operation, for example, about 10 times slower).
The specified class uses function calls from standard service programs to perform operations on the decimal type. I think that slowdown happens just because of calls of these functions.
Does anyone have any idea how to work with the decimal type from C++ programs more efficiently? Is it possible to use (directly or indirectly) the [MI DIV](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=instructions-divide-div) instruction?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt, or how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: What version of IBM i are you on?  It doesn't appear to be a new issue, judging by this [2015 post on the midrange.com C-400 mailing list](https://archive.midrange.com/c400-l/201502/msg00011.html)

Comment: I have IBM i version 7.4. In the link you provided, there is an advice to convert the decimal number to a 64 bit integer and perform all arithmetic with this number. At the end, perform the reverse transformation. Perhaps this is really the only way out ... It remains to find out how to make such a transformation. Although, in the same bcd library there is such a conversion. If only it wasn't slow again)

Comment: This may be naive, but can you structure your C++ program such that it uses a C (or RPG) module?

Comment: This approach can be applied in a particular solution, when specific types of decimal are known in advance (for example, decimal(11,7)). But I am writing a C++ library for IBM i. And what specific type of decimal the user of the library will use, obviously, is not known to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the MI `DIV` instruction is useable from ILE code. There is no bound program access provided for that instruction.

Look at the `CPYNV` instruction. Note it has a built in number used for access from ILE code:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=instructions-copy-numeric-value-cpynv

But not all MI instructions have an ILE built in number. The documentation on `DIV` does not include mention of a built in number.

Here is RPG code that runs the MI `CPYNV` instruction to copy from one RPG packed decimal variable to another.  But without the built in number, I do not think you can do something comparable from ILE RPG or ILE C for the `DIV` instruction.

```
** --------------------- conMiScalar ----------------------- 
** value of the Type field in refScalarAttr struct.          
dconMiScalar_None...                                         
d                 c                   x'ff'                  
dconMiScalar_Bin  c                   x'00'                  
dconMiScalar_Zoned...                                        
d                 c                   x'02'                  
dconMiScalar_Packed...                                       
d                 c                   x'03'                  
dconMiScalar_Char...                                         
d                 c                   x'04'                  
dconMiScalar_UBin...                                         
d                 c                   x'0a'                  

** ----------------------- refScalar ---------------------------
** MI scalar operand.                                           
drefScalar        ds                  qualified based(@)        
d type                           1a                             
d lgth                           5i 0                           
d prec                           3i 0 overlay(lgth:1)           
d digits                         3i 0 overlay(lgth:2)           
d rsv1                          10i 0         

d csno            s             10p 0                   
d pvCsno          s             10p 0                   
d scalar_csno     ds                  likeds(refScalar) 
d scalar_pvCsno   ds                  likeds(refScalar)  
d msg             s             50a   varying
 /free                                                        
      csno        = 25 ;                                      
      clear       scalar_csno ;                               
      scalar_csno.type = conMiScalar_packed ;                 
      scalar_csno.prec = 0 ;                                  
      scalar_csno.digits = 10 ;   

      clear       scalar_pvCsno ;               
      scalar_pvCsno.type = conMiScalar_packed ; 
      scalar_pvCsno.prec = 0 ;                  
      scalar_pvCsno.digits = 10 ;            

      pr_LbCpyNv( %addr(pvCsno): %addr(scalar_pvCsno):   
                  %addr(csno): %addr(scalar_csno)) ;     
                                                         
      msg         = 'pvCsno:' + %char(pvCsno) ;          
      dsply       msg ;
```